# Is it possible to enable ActionBar, but normal menu in pre-3.x Androids?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-2.2-froyo, android-menu

As described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding), you can either make an Android app with 2.x compatibility Action-bar, or compile only for 3.x+ and link the native Actionbar library.

I'd like to use the normal menu for Android 2.x, and only add some icons like back, forward, search to the Actionbar when on 3.x and 4.x devices that have the funny toolbar at top.

Is there any way to do this without creating two different apps?

Comment: By default, if you don't use `ActionBarActivity`, Android 2.x will always use normal menu and Android >3.x will always use Action Bar. Try it on emulator :)

Comment: Yes, I tried it on emulator and it looks ok on 4.x but there is only one 3-dots menu to the right. It would be better if back/forward were near each other, not having back be the back icon, and forward being under the everything menu. It's also pretty goofy that no menu items have icons newer Android unfortunately.

Comment: It should be possible to always put both Back and Forward as action button using `android:showAsAction="always"`. Perhaps you can read more about menu on [the official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: @AndrewT. Right, looks like you can target API 11, yet have lower minimum. However I'm not sure about consistent back/forward implementation.